# Facebook only shares parent page

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I've created a custom page with child pages, which in turn has their own share buttons, everything so far, the link is correctly linked to the share buttons and everything, it works perfectly with every social network with one expectation. FACEBOOK! I tried removing canonical but it didn't help... the page can be found here

http://kurdaktuellt.se/galleri/images/1598/

when you press the facebook button the url should be same as above, but somehow it become

http://kurdaktuellt.se/galleri/

even though the url is correctly set as can be seen in the url when clicking the share button

if i missed out something feel free to ask.

All help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using both

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'rel_canonical');//this didnt work you need to use the one beneath 

remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```